# Kendo UI dataSource transport calling php function

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

Greeting All,

If have this category.php files in my codes that perform CRUD function. But in Kendo UI dataSource how can I calling those function in datasource/transport? 
I used to split the php file before this, but now I want to place into one single file only.
Can anyone help me? Thank you for your time.

```html
<?php

  class Categories {

    function getCategory(){
       //codes in here
    }

    function addCategory(){
       //codes in here
    }

    function editCategory(){
       //codes in here
    }

    function deleteCategory(){
       //codes in here
    }

  }

?>
```

```js
transport: {
  read: {
    url:  "./category.php", // <---calling getCategory function
    type: "POST",
    data: function() {
          return { 
            c1: document.getElementById('c1').checked,
          }
    },
  },
  create: {
    url:  "./category.php",  // <---calling addCategory function
    type: "POST",
    complete: function (e) {  
                $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
              }
  },
  update: {
    url:  "./category.php",  // <---calling editCategory function
    type: "POST",
    complete: function (e) {  
                $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
              } 
  },
  destroy: {
    url:  "./category.php",  // <---calling deleteCategory function
    type: "POST",
    complete: function (e) {  
                $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
              } 
  },                
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after circle around, I need to add `method()` in my php files, then on my dataSource/transport need to return the method a value `data: {method: "addCategory"},` Example below.

```html
<?php
  $method = $_POST['method'];
  $method();

  class Categories {

    function getCategory(){
       //codes in here
    }

    function addCategory(){
       //codes in here
    }

    function editCategory(){
       //codes in here
    }

    function deleteCategory(){
       //codes in here
    }

  }

?>
```

```js
transport: {
  read: {
    url:  "category.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: function() {
        return { 
          method: "getCategory",
          c1: document.getElementById('c1').checked,
        }
      },
    },
  create: {
    url:  "category.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {method: "addCategory"},
    complete: function (e) {  
          $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
          }
  },
  update: {
    url:  "category.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {method: "editCategory"},
    complete: function (e) {  
          $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
          } 
  },
  destroy: {
    url:  "category.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {method: "deleteCategory"},
    complete: function (e) {  
          $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
          } 
  },                
},
```